# run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005) odbc--call failed

Tags: sql, excel, odbc, vba

I am uploading my records in excel 2007 to sql2012 database using vba.
I was using following code successfully for last 3 months but it now fails with the error below.

> run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005) odbc--call failed

My code in VBA:

```vb
Sub UpdateTable()
    Dim cnn As Object
    Dim wbkOpen As Workbook
    Dim objfl As Variant
    Dim rngName As Range
    Set wbkOpen = ActiveWorkbook
    ActiveSheet.Select
    Set rngName = Range(Range("A1"), Range("A1").End(xlToLeft).End(xlDown))
    rngName.Name = "TempRange"
    strFileName = wbkOpen.FullName
    Set cnn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strFileName & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes"";"
    nsql = "INSERT INTO [odbc;Driver=SQL Server;Server=dedr;Uid=pmac;Pwd=123456;Database=dpgrt].stmt"
    nJOIN = " SELECT * from [TempRange]"
    cnn.Execute nsql & nJOIN <<<<<<<<< this is error line.
    MsgBox "Uploaded Successfully"
    cnn.Close
    Set wbkOpen = Nothing
End Sub
```

This error just come up yesterday. There was no change in sql database.
Kindly help.